# Update multi tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables in mysql(Version:mysql 5.7.24) like this :

```
     table1                                   table2
    ------------------------------------------------------

     Name                                Name     Family
    ------                              -----------------

    Ali                                  Reza      Tab

    Hamid                                Ali       Rtg
```

I want update `Name` column in two table in 1 query so use this command:

```
$query = "
UPDATE table1
     , table2 
   SET table1.Name = 'hhh'
     , table2.Name = 'hhh' 
 WHERE table1.Name ='Hamid' 
   AND table2.Name = 'Hamid';
```

I expect the table1 to be updated but none of the tables are updated.Why?

If use `WHERE table1.Name ='Ali' AND table2.Name ='Ali';` instead of `WHERE table1.Name ='Hamid' AND table2.Name ='Hamid';` both tables are updated

Comment: The problem is that there's no `table2.Name = 'Hamid`. So when you create a cross-product between the two tables, you're crossing with an empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `AND` operator to `OR` in the `WHERE` clause and use `IF()` function to do the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET 
  table1.Name = IF(table1.Name = 'Hamid', 'hhh', table1.Name),
  table2.Name = IF(table2.Name = 'Hamid', 'hhh', table2.Name)
WHERE table1.Name = 'Hamid' OR table2.Name = 'Hamid';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hwZgENwXc4mJhrnv4Cn9E/0).
Results:
**table1**

```
| Name |
| ---- |
| Ali  |
| hhh  |
```

**table2**

```
| Name | Family |
| ---- | ------ |
| Reza | Tab    |
| Ali  | Rtg    |
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a cross-product, which has an empty result if either of the tables has no matches for its condition. It works for `Ali` because there are rows in both tables.

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
UPDATE table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.Name = table1.Name
SET table1.Name = 'hhh', table2.Name = 'hhh'
WHERE table1.Name = 'Hamid'
```

I'm assuming that `table1` is the master table, and `table2` is the dependent table.

If this is a foreign key, you can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the foreign key specification. Then you only have to update `table1` and it will automatically propagate to `table2`.

Comment: `LEFT` join, Barmar?  Not `INNER`?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Correct. `INNER JOIN` won't return anything if there's no match.